Read Timeout When Using Llama3 Model on Streamlit
This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow. I am trying to run a Llama3 model that queries a PDF file on Streamlit. It uses llama index to chunk up the text and create a vector for each chunk. When you type a query, it creates a vector embedding for the query, finds the best match from the text pieces and gives them a Llama3 model running in Ollama.
A link to the GitHub repo for this application can be found here: https://github.com/teg-lad/streamlit_rag. I have ensured to install all of the libraries mentioned in the app.py file in my venv since there is no requirements file. To run the application use Streamlit run .\app.py.
When running a query, the query runs for a few minutes before I receive a read timeout message. I receive the message "httpx.ReadTimeout: timed out" in my terminal when this happens. Immediately before the traceback for this message, I receive "Uncaught app exception".
I am not sure if this is also relevant, but when I run python .\app.py, I receive this error: "AttributeError: st.session_state has no attribute "id". Did you forget to initialize it?
I should also note that the PDF file I have used to query with the model is only 28KB in size.
I am currently using Streamlit version 1.34.0 and Python version 3.12.3.
I retried querying with the Llama3 model several times and found that I was able to successfully receive a response on one occasion only.
I initially believed it may have been a result of not running ollama pull llama3 before running the application since on the first occasion I did this it worked but has not since.
I believe the fact that I am operating this application on a cpu laptop may be resulting in my laptop being unable to handle the query before the runtime error appears.
Some of my laptop's details include that it is a HP laptop with Windows 11 installed and is a 64-bit Operating System. It has 8.00GB of RAM with 7.72Gb usable.
Please ask me if you would like more details on this issue.
